# const db = firebase.database() is not a function React native

Tags: react-native

I'm currently learning react native. I use firebase realtime database. after I initialized the configuration, I try to call .database(). but i got an error says database is not a function. anyone knows how to solve it?

import firebase from "firebase/app"

const firebaseConfig = {

```
     ....
```

}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.database();

export default firebase

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import `firebase/database` function into your project specifically. See [Setup Step 2](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Your file should look like this

```
import firebase from "firebase/app"
import "firebase/database"

const firebaseConfig = {

    ....
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const db = firebase.database();

export default firebase;
```